# Using NASM as inline assembler compiler in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, nasm, inline-assembly

I managed to set NASM as compiler for separate .asm files, but I can't find a way to set NASM as compiler for inline assembler (__asm directive). For example,

```
helloWorld    db    "Hello world !",0
```

won't compile (assembler syntax error, found "db").
Is there a way to do that ? Or am I bound to use MASM or use another development environment ? 
Thanks !

ps : by the way the MSDN doesn't give any clue :D

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the inline assembler is built-in (isn't MASM), and can't be plug-replaced.

You can use an external assembler (e.g. MASM) by itself (not as an 'inline' assembler) to create object (`*.obj`) files, and then link these object files to your C++ code using the linker.

Comment: With NASM it's likely that the object files will have .o extension.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93(v=vs.90).aspx) explicitly say that it is built in:

> The inline assembler is built into the compiler, so you don't need a separate assembler such as the Microsoft Macro Assembler (MASM).

And no, there is no way to use plugins.  If you could, adding support for other platforms (ARM, x64, etc) would be easy, instead of being completely unsupported.